# iFrame jquery auto resizing not working

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm using a jquery script to autoresize an iframe. It was working fine till now, but I made a lot of changes to the site and suddenly it stopped working and I found with Chrome dev tools the JS was giving this error message:

Cannot read property of "body" undefined.

I removed everything from the code and just left a call to jquery and the resizing script in the head:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iframe.js"></script>
</head>
```

and the iframe in the body.

```
<body>
<iframe src="http://chusmix.com" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

However it's still not working. I don't know what else to do. I'm testing it here:

http://www.chusmix.com/game/testframe.php

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a security issue.  The URL you are going to to view it is http://**www**.chusmix.com and the iframe is http://chusmix.com (no www) so the browser is not allowing you to access the iframe's document (hence it is undefined).

Go to http://chusmix.com/game/testframe.php and you will see that it works.

Comment: thanks, it's true it works without www. however I added www. to the iframe's path and still it only works in http://chusmix. Do you have any ideas why? I can do a raw fix but I'd rather have it ok from the go. Thanks

Comment: Going to www.chusmix.com forwards to chusmix.com (no www).  So even though you're putting www in the src, it is being forwarded to the non-www.  Because of that it's still a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add the following attribute to the iframe element which will simply do the job for you:

```
onload="$(this).height($(this.contentWindow.document.body).height());"
```